# Character-encoding problem with string literal in source code (utf8 no bom)

Tags: powershell, utf-8, character-encoding, codepages, invoke-command

```
$logstring = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $filesServer   -ScriptBlock {
        param(
            $logstring,
            $grp
        )

    $Klassenbuchordner = "KB " + $grp.Gruppe
    $Gruppenordner = $grp.Gruppe
    $share = $grp.Gruppe
    $path = "D:\Gruppen\$Gruppenordner"

    if ((Test-Path D:\Dozenten\01_Klassenbücher\$Klassenbuchordner) -eq $true)
    {$logstring += "Verzeichnis für Klassenbücher existiert bereits"}
    else {
        mkdir D:\Dozenten\01_Klassenbücher\$Klassenbuchordner
        $logstring += "Klassenbuchordner wurde erstellt!"
    }} -ArgumentList $logstring, $grp
```

My goal is to test the existence of a directory and create it on demand.

The problem is that the path contains German letters (umlauts), which aren't seen correctly by the target server.

For instance, the server receives path `"D:\Dozent\01_KlassenbÃ¼cher"` instead of the expected `"D:\Dozent\01_Klassenbücher"`.

How can I force proper UTF-8 encoding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: **Remoting and use of `Invoke-Command` are *incidental* to your problem**.

Since the problem occurs with a *string literal* in your *source code* (`...\01_Klassenbücher\...`), the likeliest explanation is that your *script file is misinterpreted by PowerShell*.

In ***Windows PowerShell***, if **your script file is de facto UTF-8-encoded but *lacks a BOM***, the PowerShell engine will **misinterpret any non-ASCII-range characters** (such as `ü`) in the script.<sup>[1]</sup>

Therefore: **Re-save your script as UTF-8 *with BOM***.<sup>[2]</sup>

Note:

- A UTF-8 BOM is no longer strictly necessary in the install-on-demand, cross-platform [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition (which consistently *defaults* to (BOM-less) UTF-8), but continues to be required if you want your scripts to work in *both* PowerShell editions.

---

##### Why you should save your scripts as UTF-8 with BOM:

**Visual Studio Code** and other modern editors create UTF-8 files *without BOM* by default, which is what causes the problem in Windows PowerShell.

By contrast, the PowerShell ISE creates "ANSI"-encoded<sup>[1]</sup> files, which Windows PowerShell - but not PowerShell *Core* - reads correctly.

You can only get away with "ANSI"-encoded files:

- if your scripts will never be run in PowerShell *Core* - where all future development effort will go.
- if your scripts will never run on a machine where a *different* "ANSI" code page is in effect.
- if your script doesn't contain characters - e.g., emoji - that cannot be represented with your "ANSI" code page.

Given these limitations, **it's safest - and future-proof - to always create PowerShell scripts as *UTF-8 with BOM***.
(Alternatively, you can use UTF-16 (which is always saved *with* a BOM), but that bloats the file size unnecessarily if you're primarily using ASCII/"ANSI"-range characters, which is likely in PS scripts).

---

##### How to make Visual Studio Code create UTF-8 files *with-BOM* for PowerShell scripts *by default*:

Note: The following is still required as of v1.11.0 of the [PowerShell extension for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell), but not that there's a **suggestion to make the extension *default* PowerShell files to UTF-8 *with BOM* [on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1771)**.

Add the following to your `settings.json` file (from the command palette (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd>, type `settings` and select `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`):

```bash
"[powershell]": {
  "files.encoding": "utf8bom"
}
```

Note that the **setting is intentionally scoped to *PowerShell* files only**, because you wouldn't want *all* files to default to UTF-8 *with BOM*, given that many utilities on Unix platforms neither expect nor know how to handle such a BOM.

---

<sup>[1] In the absence of a BOM, Windows PowerShell defaults to the encoding of the system's current "ANSI" code page, as determined by the legacy system locale; e.g., in Western European cultures, Windows-1252.</sup>

<sup>[2] To fix this problem for a given file in Visual Studio Code: With the file of interest open, click on `UTF-8` in the status bar near the right edge, then choose `Save with Encoding` and select `UTF-8 with BOM`.</sup>