# powershell script not working but codes are working?

Tags: powershell

```
$CSharpSig = @'
[DllImport(“user32.dll”, EntryPoint = “SystemParametersInfo”)]

public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(

                 uint uiAction,

                 uint uiParam,

                 uint pvParam,

                 uint fWinIni);

'@

$CursorRefresh = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $CSharpSig -Name WinAPICall -Namespace SystemParamInfo –PassThru
$CursorRefresh::SystemParametersInfo(0x0057,0,$null,0)
```

- this script refreshs mouse cursor
- if you run this script will not work !
- but if you copy & Paste the codes in powershell
- it will work !
- I don't know how

Comment: What do you mean by run the script? Right click and "run with PowerShell"?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon yes

Comment: [1] if you load the code into the powershell.exe console [not the ISE], does it run there? ///// [2] if you add `pause` to the end of the script and then run in via right-click, does it show any errors?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey script is crashing I tryed adding pause to the end. 
but it's crashing not showing any errors... Only Working by pasting codes in powershell interface (not ISE)

Comment: @AbdullahNabil - thank you for the added detail. PLEASE, add that info [& any other info you have] to your Question so  that folks can easily find it.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey basiclly I wanna make a script to do this commands and add it to my C# App. But I invoke all of that commands so I wanna make a script to do this...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey More Details ? I am changing the mouse scheme from registry [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors] and It will be applied when you restart your PC...But this commands working good to refresh the cursor ! tested many times.

Comment: @AbdullahNabil - you have provided details in the comments that are not in the Question. you will have better luck getting useful help if you add those details to the Question where they will be easy for people to find. ///// you are well beyond my skill level at this point, so all i can do to help you is provide advice on how to make a Question that is easy to understand AND complete.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely related to the character encoding, maybe due to the ps1 being saved without a [BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789907/character-encoding-problem-with-string-literal-in-source-code/54790355#54790355) as VS likes to do, so your quotes are being misinterpreted.

To quickly test, copy/paste this line into your code instead and I bet it'll work fine.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]
```