# PowerShell - Set-AzureADUserExtension with Polish Characters

Tags: powershell

I want to set the value "Wrocław" in ExtensionValue.

Using the Set-AzureADUserExtension command with parameters -ObjectId "XYZ," -ExtensionName "XYZ1," and -ExtensionValue "WROCŁAW."

Regrettably, PowerShell is unable to perform this task.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

I am trying add utf8

Comment: Since the problem occurs with a _string literal_ in your _source code_, the likeliest explanation is that your script file is misinterpreted by the _Windows PowerShell_ engine, which happens if the script is saved as UTF-8 _without a BOM_ (this is no longer a problem in [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.me)). Try saving your script as UTF-8 _with BOM_. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54790355/45375) for more information.

Comment: I have had trouble with character sets so regularly that my Powershell template file was saved as utf8-bom explicitly

Comment: Impossible! I changed in notepad++ from utf8 to utf8 with boom and it works!