# Select a value from a property from an object with a ß (or special carater) in the property name in powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, special-characters

I have a list of addresses in an Excel spreadsheet. In this table, the columns are described with special characters. For example, the German word for street: "Straße".

I need to change some of these values and write them to a new file.

However, I cannot access values that contain an ß in the property name within the foreach loop. The values simply remain empty in the object at this point. Even if I try to output something via write-output, it does not work.

If I try to access the data outside the loop, I get the data displayed.

```
$excelFilePath = "C:\adress.xls"
$data = Import-Excel -Path $excelFilePath

#displays the roads:
$data."Straße"

$Results = foreach ( $adress in $data  ) {

#also empty:
Write-Output $adress."Straße"

     [pscustomobject]@{
    #other values...
        'Street'  = $adress."Straße"
      }
}
    
$Results | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

I tried to display the values with curly brackets and other tips on how to deal with special letters, but unfortunately that didn't help.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: there is no issue with that character: `([pscustomobject]@{ Straße = '123' }).Straße` works fine. ensure that the column header has no white space at start or end otherwise we need a example to reproduce in order to properly help.

Comment: Since the problem occurs with _string literals_ in your _source code_, the likeliest explanation is that your script file is misinterpreted by the _Windows PowerShell_ engine, which happens if the script is saved as UTF-8 _without a BOM_ (this is no longer a problem in _PowerShell (Core) 7+_. Try saving your script as UTF-8 _with BOM_.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54790355/45375) for details. If that alone doesn't solve your problem, the implication is that the XML file isn't being read correctly or there's no property by that name.

Comment: Probably not a utf8 *with bom* script, or as an awkward workaround:  `"Stra$([char]0xdf)e"`

Comment: The solution with "Stra$([char]0xdf)e" worked.

Saving the whole script as "utf8boom" and leaving "Straße" also worked. Another lesson learnt. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Running powershell 5.1 scripts encoded in utf8 no bom is a frequent question, but it's hard to find a stackoverflow entry with a lot of google juice.